# How to add a filter to all widget output

Tags: widgets, nofollow, filters

Is there one last filter that is ran over the widgets before they are sent out to the browser? I would like to add a filter that adds `rel="nofollow"` to all links in all widgets.

For instance, I can add a filter to the text widget:

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'xrvel_nfp_modify_nofollow');
```

But I don't want to hunt down every single hook for every widget. (Also, the RSS widget doesn't even HAVE a filter. [Trac ticket submitted](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16648))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another thread on here that discusses a workaround.

Well... the familiar php workaround when a function does not provide a "get to variable" output actually... use ob_start: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
to just capture the output and manipulate it before sending it on its way.

Leads on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bwordpress+sidebar+%2Bob-start+

Answer (score 2):

The output is completely up to each individual widget. It is echoed directly by the widget's `widget()` method, so there's no general filters that apply to all of them.

Comment: That's poop. I was afraid that was the case.